# How do I make a JButton go from one GUI to the other?

Tags: java, swing

I am supposed to made a code that opens a maze. The maze code is working fine, but I need a "splash screen" that will load first, then will open a menu that asks "Would you like to play?" with yes and no options. The part I am stuck on is making the 'yes' and 'no' buttons. When 'yes' is pressed, it's supposed to open the maze GUI that has been typed up in another class. Can someone help me write a code that will have a button that will open up the second class?

I'm using Eclipse IDE with Java.

EDIT: I put the code for the splash screen up, but I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing. I'm very new to Java and any help is appreciated!

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SplashScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    Image img =     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/splash.png");
    ImageIcon imgicon = new ImageIcon(img);

    public SplashScreen() {
        try {
            setSize(633, 300);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            show();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            dispose();
            int input = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Welcome     to the Maze Game! Would you like to play?", "Select an Option...",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

            // 0=yes, 1=no, 2=cancel
            System.out.println(input);

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((java.awt.Component) null,     "Error" + exception.getMessage(),
                    "Error:", javax.swing.JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SplashScreen sp = new SplashScreen();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you look into JOptionPane with YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION

Comment: I have that, but I don't know how to make the buttons do anything

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 3) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score 0):

A few things here: I think you would rather add your maze to a JPanel, and then just have that JPanel take up the entire JFrame. That way you can just replace the JPanel - no need to have multiple JFrames. Also make sure you run your GUI using the event-dispatching thread, to avoid unwanted GUI behavior (as I've shown below).

See my example below, I create a simple program that will display JPanel one (green) or two (blue) depending on the option you choose from the JOptionPane:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * This program has two JPanels - one green and one blue.
 * The JOptionPane controls which JPanel is displayed.
 */
public class Test {
    private JFrame jf;
    private JPanel one;
    private JPanel two;

    /**
     * ALWAYS start a Java GUI from the event-dispatching thread!
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * An instance of the program is constructed.
     */
    public Test() {
        jf = new JFrame("Test");

        addComponents(jf.getContentPane());
        showOptions();

        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.pack();
    }

    /**
     * Add components to the pane of our JFrame.
     * You probably want to set the layout manager.
     * @param pane
     */
    public void addComponents(Container pane) {
        one = new JPanel();
        one.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        one.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        two = new JPanel();
        two.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        two.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        // We've added the GREEN JPanel - that's it
        pane.add(one);
    }

    /**
     * Show the option pane.
     */
    public void showOptions() {
        int input = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Show the blue JPanel?", "Select an Option...", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if (input == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            jf.getContentPane().remove(one); // Removing our default green JPanel
            jf.getContentPane().add(two); // Adding our shiny new blue JPanel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use magic numbers: "0" and "1". Use the variables provided by the API: `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` and `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it out :)

Answer (score -1):

So i have an old Java project and i just took a look to help you out. So you need to connect 2 GUI's with each-other. After you press Yes the one you have closes and another one appears i guess.
So in GUI when i right clicked on the button Go to Events, Action and pick Action Performed and it will redirect you to the source. There i had only this code:

```
     Array a = new Array();
     a.setVisible(true);
     a.setDefaultCloseOperation(Array.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

I hope it helped

Comment: This is just incorrect... Array does not have the methods of a JFrame... I'm not sure what you're talking about. Consider deleting this.

Comment: I agree, this is really nonsensical.

Comment: I have a file called Array.java so i connected to that file by adding that code and it redirects there after you click the button. @rey write me down i can give you the whole project